# Как организовать отображение preview youtube

Tags: android, youtube, preview

Суть в том, что у меня есть лист, который может содержать изображения и превьюшки yotube. 
Получаю превью таким образом  `https://img.youtube.com/vi/<id видеозаписи>/hqdefault.jpg`, но получаю просто изображение, а как сделать так, чтобы пользователь понимал, что по клику на изображение его перекинет на сайт youtube и чтобы было можно было навесить listener.

Answer (score 1):

Есть небольшое противоречие:

> получаю просто изображение.
>   а как сделать так, чтобы пользователь понимал, что это видео.

По ссылке должно быть понятно, это видео или картинка:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<ID>/hqdefault.jpg # картинка
https://www.youtube.com/embed/<ID> # видео
```

Чтобы по картинке было понятно, что это есть возможность посмотреть видео, наложите с помощью **css** кнопку видео-плеера на картинку.

Чтобы по клику воспроизводить видео, вешайте onClick, который будет подгружать видео c youtube, в iframe, наверное:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<ID>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте на это превью длительность, думаю более чем понятно(надеюсь правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: проблема в том, что у меня есть лист, в котором могут встречаться как изображения, так и видео, поэтому мне нужно определять это еще и программно

Comment: @kalugin1912 Я не достаточно опытен для такого, думаю более опытные пользователи вам помогут, а из моих соображений если вы будете получать из сети длительность то сделайте проверку если при попытке получить длительность функция происходит успешно то программно добавляйте длительность на ваш элемент.

Comment: но все равно ,  спасибо большое)